# Does Windows 7 store domain account and password in SAM

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

If my machine has Windows 7 and connect to domain, what happens when domain controller is unavailable ?

How do I exactly log in when domain controller is unavailable ?

I mean normally it should use Kerberos, and it should fall back to NTLM.

Does that mean domain account and password hash are stored in SAM ?

Comment: You can disabled cached credentials - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755473(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows will log you on with cached credentials as long as you have successfully logged on to the domain once. The user name and password are not cached on the local machine, a password verifier is cached on the local machine in the registry. As far as I know it's not possible to directly access or edit the registry hive where the password verifier is written.

Comment: So what kinda authentication method does windows use during offline ?